# convert html form into pdf in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, puppeteer

I have created a class that converts a HTML file into pdf. Below is code

```
class Invoice {  
  async html() {
    try {
      const data = {
        your: 'data'
      }
      console.log("Current directory:", __dirname); 

      const templatePath = Path.resolve('index.html')
      console.log(templatePath)
      const content = await ReadFile(templatePath, 'utf8')
      // compile and render the template with handlebars
      const template = Handlebars.compile(content)
      return template(data)
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Cannot create invoice HTML template.')
    }
  }

  async pdf() {
    const html = await this.html()
    console.log(html)
    const browser = await Puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setContent(html)
    return page.pdf()
  }
}
```

But this read an HTML file located on disk. But I want to create pdf of an HTML form in an html file.

Please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: `an HTML form in an html file` do you mean the user is filling out a form in the browser and submitting it?

Comment: yes. after filling I can generate PDF of it

Comment: Instead of hardcoding your class to use `this.html()`, make it a parameter of the pdf() function. Then send the form data to the server, compose the html and use the existing function.

Comment: can you tell me how can i do that ?

Comment: I basically just did, so you need to be more specific. What exactly would you like to know? You have a `const data` in your code; all you need to do is use the submitted form data instead.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)? As per their website, jsPDF is a leading HTML5 client solution for generating PDFs. Perfect for event tickets, reports & certificates.